# Moments of min of a random variable and a constant.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, expectation

Let $X$ be a random variables with Normal distribution: $N[m,\sigma^2]$. Let $\eta$ be a constant. Now, let $M=\min(X,\eta)$. What is the expectation and variance of $M$?

This question seems related but no one answered that quesion: [Expectation of $\min(X, c)$ for $X$ truncated r.v. and $c$ constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1367607/expectation-of-minx-c-for-x-truncated-r-v-and-c-constant)

This question also seems related but it talks same about two or more random varible which is uniformly distributed: [Expectation of Minimum of $n$ i.i.d. uniform random variables.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786392/expectation-of-minimum-of-n-i-i-d-uniform-random-variables/786426#786426)

I tried to explicitly calculate the probability distribution of $M$, but it turned out too complicated.

Here is my current attempt; looking forward for your comments.)

---

$E[M]=E[min(X,\eta)] =min(E[X],\eta) = min(m,\eta)$

$var[M]=var[min(X,\eta)]= min(var[X],\eta^2)= min(\sigma^2,\eta^2)$

Comment: we cannot exchange the order of expectation and minimum function, I still dont know the answer, I'll try it, if I get something, I'll share to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z_{\eta}\equiv(\eta-m)/\sigma$. Then

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X\wedge \eta]=&E[X1\{X\le \eta\}]+\eta \mathbb{E}[1\{X>\eta\}] \\
=&m\Phi(z_{\eta})-\sigma\phi(z_{\eta})+\eta(1-\Phi(z_{\eta})),
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[(X\wedge \eta)^2]=&\mathbb{E}[X^21\{X\le \eta\}]+\eta^2 \mathbb{E}[1\{X>\eta\}] \\
=&(m^2+\sigma^2)\Phi(z_{\eta})-\sigma(m+\eta)\phi(z_{\eta})+\eta^2(1-\Phi(z_{\eta})),
\end{align}

and

$$
Var(X\wedge \eta)=\mathbb{E}[(X\wedge \eta)^2]-(\mathbb{E}[X\wedge \eta])^2.
$$

Comment: I like your solution far better than mine.

Comment: There is a confusion between the random variable $x$ and $\eta$. It will be better if you could have taken different variable then $\eta$.

Comment: @imtiyazkhan What do you mean by a confusion between $x$ and $\eta$?

Comment: @d.k.o As you know I took $\eta$ as a constant. But you included $\eta$ in your variable $z_{\eta}$ as another variable. It makes me confuse which $\eta$ is a variable and which $\eta$ is constant

Comment: @imtiyazkhan $z_{\eta}$ is also a constant. $\eta$ in its definition is the same $\eta$ you used in the question...

Comment: @d.k.o. Thanks. One more thing is that make me uncomfortable when I see $X1, X^21$. Why you included those $1$ everywhere. Please also give me the reference from you took or inspired for this answer.

Comment: @imtiyazkhan $1_A$ is the indicator of set $A$. So $X1\{X\le \eta\}=X$ on the set $\{X\le \eta\}$ and is $0$ otherwise. Also 
$$
X\wedge \eta=(X\wedge \eta)1\{X\le \eta\}+(X\wedge \eta)1\{X> \eta\} \\
=X\times 1\{X\le \eta\}+\eta\times 1\{X> \eta\}.
$$

Comment: @d.k.o. Thanks ) It helps. But what about reference??

Comment: @imtiyazkhan Actually, it is a standard trick. I'm not sure what type of reference you are asking about?

Comment: @d.k.o. Thanks. Your answer helped me alot. Now first line is understandable to me. But how do you get  $m\Phi(z_{\eta})-\sigma\phi(z_{\eta})+\eta(1-\Phi(z_{\eta}))$  from $E[X1\{X\le \eta\}]+\eta \mathbb{E}[1\{X>\eta\}] $

Comment: $$\mathbb{E}[1\{X>\eta\}]=\mathbb{P}\{X>\eta\}=1-\Phi(z_\eta),$$

$$\mathbb{E}[X1\{X\le\eta\}]=\mathbb{E}[X\mid X\le\eta]\times \mathbb{P}\{X\le \eta\}$$

For $\mathbb{E}[X\mid X\le\eta]$ you may look here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution.

Otherwise, you may calculate $\mathbb{E}[X1\{X\le\eta\}]$ directly (as heropup showed).

Comment: Thanks alot )). Please help me to answer my this question as well http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2007971/mean-and-variance-of-random-variable-having-min-function

Comment: Hi, Can you help me how you have calculated \begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[(X\wedge \eta)^2]=&\mathbb{E}[X^21\{X\le \eta\}]+\eta^2 \mathbb{E}[1\{X>\eta\}] \\
=&(m^2+\sigma^2)\Phi(z_{\eta})-\sigma(m+\eta)\phi(z_{\eta})+\eta^2(1-\Phi(z_{\eta})),
\end{align} because when I am trying to find in the simailar fashion I am not getting the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Directly, $$\operatorname{E}[(\min(X, \eta))^k] = \int_{x=-\infty}^\eta x^k f_X(x) \, dx + \int_{x=\eta}^\infty \eta^k f_X(x) \, dx.$$  The second term is simply $\eta^k (1 - F_X(\eta)) = \eta^k \left( 1 - \Phi(\frac{\eta - \mu}{\sigma})\right)$.  The first term is more challenging.  For $k = 1$, we write $$\int_{x=-\infty}^\eta x f_X(x) \, dx = \mu F_X(\eta) + \sigma^2 \int_{x=-\infty}^\eta \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma^2} f_X(x) \, dx$$ and with the substitution $$z = \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}, \quad dz = \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma^2} \, dx,$$ we get $$\int_{x=-\infty}^\eta x f_X(x) \, dx = \mu F_X(\eta) + \sigma^2 \int_{z=\infty}^{(\eta - \mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)} \frac{e^{-z}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \, dz = \mu F_X(\eta) - \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(\eta-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)}.$$  Thus $$\operatorname{E}[\min(X , \eta)] = \eta + (\mu-\eta) \, \Phi\!\left(\tfrac{\eta - \mu}{\sigma}\right) - \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(\eta - \mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)}.$$  The solution for $k = 2$ is similar, but more tedious; therefore I have left it as an exercise.  The resulting computation is then used to obtain the variance.

Comment: Hi, Please help me to answer my this question as well http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2007971/variance-of-random-variable-having-min-function?noredirect=1#comment4123131_2007971