# Moments of minimum of a Gaussian random variable and a constant.

Tags: probability, complex-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Consider $X=X_r+jX_i$  to be a circularly symmetric Gaussian random variable, and $$X\sim\mathcal{N}_c(0,\sigma^2)$$ where $\mathcal{N_c}$ denotes the Gaussian distribution for complex random variable. Here $X_r$ and $X_i$ are the real and the imaginary parts of $X$. Due to circularly symmetry assumption, zero mean random variables $X_r$ and $X_i$ are independent and identically distributed (i.i.d) with each $$X_r\sim\mathcal{N_r}(0,\sigma^2/2)$$ $$X_i\sim\mathcal{N_r}(0,\sigma^2/2)$$ where $\mathcal{N_r}$ denotes the Gaussian distribution for real random variable. Now, I want to calculate Variance of $$\mathbb{Var}[\min(|X|,\eta)]$$

> This Question I already asked but for Real random variable. [Moments of min of a random variable and a constant.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1998682/moments-of-min-of-a-random-variable-and-a-constant). 
>   Let $z_{\eta}\equiv(\eta-m)/\sigma$. Then
>   \begin{align}
> \mathbb{E}[X\wedge \eta]=&E[X1\{X\le \eta\}]+\eta \mathbb{E}[1\{X>\eta\}] \\
> =&m\Phi(z_{\eta})-\sigma\phi(z_{\eta})+\eta(1-\Phi(z_{\eta})),
> \end{align}
>   \begin{align}
> \mathbb{E}[(X\wedge \eta)^2]=&\mathbb{E}[X^21\{X\le \eta\}]+\eta^2 \mathbb{E}[1\{X>\eta\}] \\
> =&(m^2+\sigma^2)\Phi(z_{\eta})-\sigma(m+\eta)\phi(z_{\eta})+\eta^2(1-\Phi(z_{\eta})),
> \end{align}
>   and
>   $$
> Var(X\wedge \eta)=\mathbb{E}[(X\wedge \eta)^2]-(\mathbb{E}[X\wedge \eta])^2.
> $$

I want to know what will be the changes if Random variable is complex

Comment: Naturally there is no ordering for complex number, so perhaps you need to re-define your question

Comment: Thanks. Now I have redefined my question. I hope now it make sense.

Comment: I do not see the differences yet. As $X$ is complex, how do you define the order of complex number? You need to define the relations $>$, $<$ for the minimum function....

Comment: I don't understand which relation you mean for minimum function. What I want to say is here $\eta$ is constant and $X$ is complex number. So in $\min(X,\eta)$ how should I define  the relations $>$, $<$ for the minimum function.

Comment: How do you define $a + bi > c + di$? If this is undefined then $\min(X, \eta)$ is also undefined

Comment: Sorry for my mistake now I changed it to $min(|X|,\eta)$. I hope now it make sense.